# SQL - query tables related in two different ways

Tags: sql, join

Imagine I have a MySQL database for managing a library, and I want to know about all members that have either borrowed or reserved it. I am looking for a single query, sorted by book ID.

The tables are book, borrow, reserve and member. Both the borrow and reserve tables contain a book ID and member ID.

I only want one unique pair of book ID and member ID in the result. This means these cases need to be deduplicated

1. a member reserved a book and borrowed it also
2. a member borrowed or reserved the book multiple times

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: please show us sample table structure with data in it.

Comment: Will make an SqlFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION`, as it eliminates repeated results.

```
SELECT user_id, book_id FROM borrow
UNION
SELECT user_id, book_id FROM reserve;
```

You can refer `SQLFiddle` example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b8b44/7

Comment: Wow too fast nice work! Join was the wrong approach.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` in each select is useless as `UNION` already implies a `DISTINCT`

Comment: a) `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, b) it is not specific for `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Indeed `DISTINCT` is not needed here, my bad. Updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it becomes useful as soon as you select another column, if that column is not part of a condition in the WHERE clause, the DISTINCT becomes required

Comment: @BenE.: no it does not. `distinct` operates on all columns in the select list. And `UNION` does exactly the same thing. The where clause is irrelevant for the distinct operation

Comment: I eat my words. You are correct. Thanks for setting us straight @a_horse_with_no_name